# How to properly use UMats in ML models (Python OpenCV)?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu

I'm trying to create a GPU-powered BOVW model that uses KAZE descriptors and an SVM model to classify objects. But I'm getting an error that I can't get around, and I did not find anything in the documentation about it.

More specifically, I'm loading an image, extracting KAZE descriptors, using the BOVW model to extract clustered indexes and passing those to a SVM model.

```
image = cv2.imread('/path/to/image.jpg')
image = cv2.UMat(image)

# feature_extractor = cv2.KAZE_create
# bow_extract = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor, pretrained
# svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create(), pretrained

kp = feature_extractor.detect(image)
bowsig = bow_extract.compute(image=image, keypoints=kp)
prediction = svm.predict(bowsig)
```

The error occurs in `bow_extract.compute(image=image, keypoints=kp)`:

`TypeError: image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

Now, in the [docs for cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d6b/classcv_1_1BOWImgDescriptorExtractor.html) the compute function accepts [InputArray](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html), that could also be a UMat...

And now I'm stumped. Should I convert inplace the variables that can use GPU in my code to cv2.UMat (`image` in `feature_extractor.detect(image)` and `bowsig` in `svm.predict(bowsig)`) and forget about computing BOVW features on GPU?

Comment: Counter check if the version of OpenCV version you are using match the version of the documentation you are reading.
The version of OpenCV in python can be optain by : cv2.__version__

Comment: I'm using 3.4.1, and the documentation still says that InputArray can be an UMat array:
[BOWImgDescriptorExtractor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d6b/classcv_1_1BOWImgDescriptorExtractor.html)
[InputArray](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html)

Comment: Well from my own experience UMat array in python are not supported.
I do not really know why but I experience that once with the command merge that in C++ support very well std::vector<cv::UMat>, could not handle not a list a tuple or a set of cv2.UMat.